# How create text box which not allow blank space using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new in javascript I want to create textbox which not allows blank space, I don't want to allow paste blank space also. Using jquery I can do it simply but I want to do it using javascript my jquery code is below,

```
$("input#UserName").on({
  keydown: function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32)
      return false;
  },
  change: function() {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
  }
});
```

I want to do the same thing using javascript help me, please ....

Comment: Check my solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `addEventListener` to add listener. You can also use `onInput` to merge both events.

```js
var text = document.getElementById('txtText');
text.addEventListener('input', function(e){
  var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, '')
  if(keyCode === 32) return;
})
```

```html
<input type='text' id="txtText">
```

Comment: sir when I paste anything in this textbox then it paste space also

Comment: sir when I click on run code snippet and paste anything which considered space it paste space also

Comment: My bad. Test now.

Comment: sir is there any way to replace blank space with dash(-)

Comment: what do you mean by Blank space? entire input is blank then value should be `-`?

Comment: @SmartDeveloper instead of this line this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, '') add  this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, '-')

Comment: sir actually I want to make textbox for insert url and i want to replace all the space with dash

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to detect space

```
<input type="text" name="test" id="test">

document.getElementById("test").onkeypress = function (evt) {
        var k = evt ? evt.which : window.event.keyCode;
        if (k == 32) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

To detected pest event. Please check below code. It will remove white space onblur event

```
document.getElementById("test").onblur = function (evt) {
       var x = document.getElementById("test");
       x.value = x.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
}
```

Comment: thanks, bro but when I paste anything in the textbox then space is allowed

Comment: @SmartDeveloper properly check your textbox id!

Comment: I have checked it properly it's working when I type anything in textbox then it not allows space but when I paste anything which considers space then it paste space also

Answer (score 0):

Here the transcription of your jQuery code

```js
var input = document.getElementById("UserName");
if (input) {
  input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (key === 32) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
  input.addEventListener('change', function(){
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
  });
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="UserName">
```

Comment: I don't have any space in my input box  :/. What exactly _is not working_ ?

Comment: sir when I paste anything in this textbox then it paste space also

Comment: When you leave the input, the space is removed

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**HTML :**

```
<input type="text" value="" maxlength="30" name="email" id="UserName">
```

**Javascript :**

```
document.getElementById("UserName").onkeypress = function(e) {
if (e.which == 32) {
return false;
}
}
```

**Demo : [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/tsLpY/91/)**

Comment: when I paste anything then it allow for blank space