# ASP.NET and C#: remove spaces from asp.TextBox when typing and pasting

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, removing-whitespace

There is a nice solution to accomplish what I am after [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40106224/5490188), where they use this javascript function:

```
var text = document.getElementById('txtText');
text.addEventListener('input', function(e){
  var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, '')
  if(keyCode === 32) return;
})
```

which is applied to the following element:

```
<input type='text' id="txtText">
```

In my case, I don't have an `<input...` element, but an `<asp:TextBox` element, and the function above isn't working. I am using the correct element ID but I can still paste and also type white spaces. What am I missing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting Textbox value in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039544/getting-textbox-value-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a Class name and bind the script to the elemens with that class. Then you don't need ClientID and it works for multiple elements.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="NoSpaces"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="NoSpaces"></asp:TextBox>

<script>
    $('.NoSpaces').bind('keyup blur', function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g, '')
        if (keyCode === 32) return;
    });
</script>
```

If you do want to use ClientID, then do this

```
$('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').bind('keyup blur', function (e) {
```

However if the input is not an aspnet control (`asp:TextBox` or input with `runat=server`) then it wont work. Another issue with ClientID is that the script needs to be inline on the page containing that control.

Comment: This worked! Still can't get my head around why the solution with `'<%= txtText.ClientID%>'` isn't working...

Comment: I've added more examples.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you don't select Textbox item properly.

You can get the control ID for HTML markup that is generated by ASP.NET by using `ClientID` as following:

```
var text = document.getElementById('<%= txtText.ClientID%>');
```